# First client IP which connects to the server is always 0.0.0.0 but I set 127.0.0.1 in the client

Tags: c, sockets

## Preface

Here is question about client IP address.

I use IO multiplexing create a simple chat group, but I find the first client IP which connect to the server always `0.0.0.0`, but I set `127.0.0.1` in the client.

### Reproduction steps

1. start server with command `gcc server.c -o server && echo "compile finished" && ./server`
2. start first client `gcc client.c -o client`
3. start first client `gcc client.c -o client`, then Ctrl-C, interrupt second client.

with these steps, you can see the first client IP is `0.0.0.0`

## Code

### server

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <setjmp.h>


#define SERVER_PORT 9098
#define MAX_OR_ADD_LENGTH 100
#define MAX_NAME_SIZE 40

int main(void){
    /*
     * create an array about three socket fd, the first is server
     * */
    int array_fds[3], array_index = 1;
    int max_fd_p;
    int server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0), client_fd;
    // create
    if(server_fd == -1){
        perror("create socket descriptor error:");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char message[1024];
    socklen_t len;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &server_addr.sin_addr) != 1){
        perror("alloc address error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) != 0){
        perror("bind error:");
        exit(-1);
    }
    listen(server_fd, 1000);
    //
    ssize_t n;
    //
    array_fds[0] = server_fd;
    max_fd_p = server_fd + 1;
    fd_set fds;
    while (1){
        // IO multiplexing
        int max_resp;
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
        //
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            // if exit not add to select read list
            if(array_fds[i] != -1){
                FD_SET(array_fds[i], &fds);
            }
        }
        if((max_resp = select(max_fd_p, &fds, NULL, NULL, NULL)) == -1){
            perror("select error");
            break;
        }
        for(int i=2; i>=0 && max_resp ;i--){
            if(!FD_ISSET(array_fds[i], &fds)){
                continue;
            }
            max_resp--;
            if(array_fds[i] == server_fd){
                client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &len);
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client_addr.sin_addr, message, sizeof(message));
                printf("ip is %s\n", message);
                array_fds[array_index] = client_fd;
                // add to select read list
                if(client_fd >= max_fd_p){
                    // update maxfdp
                    max_fd_p = client_fd + 1;
                }
                array_index++;
                continue;
            }
            if((n = read(array_fds[i], message, 1024)) != -1) {
                if(n == 0){
                    // if client exit, close and remove it;
                    array_fds[i] = -1;
                    close(array_fds[i]);
                    continue;
                }
                if(write(array_fds[i], "ok, got your message", n) == -1){
                    perror("write error");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

### client

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define SERVER_PORT 9098

int main(void){
    int client_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(client_fd == -1){
        perror("create socket error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    client_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    client_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &client_addr.sin_addr.s_addr) == -1){
        perror("address error:");
        exit(-1);
    }
    if(connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr)) == -1){
        perror("connect error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    char message[1024], input_message[1024];
    ssize_t n;
    printf("input your name:");
    fgets(input_message, 1024, stdin);
    if(write(client_fd, input_message, 1024) == -1){
        perror("write error");
    }
    while (1){
        memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
        if((n = read(client_fd, message, 1024)) != -1){
            message[n] = 0;
            printf("[server]: %s\n", message);
        }
        memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
        printf("input message you want to send:");
        fgets(input_message, 1024, stdin);

        if(write(client_fd, input_message, 1024) == -1){
            perror("write error");
        }

    }
}
```

## Screenshots

[image]

Comment: @ArtSpasky I add server and client code in the `Code` section, it's too long, I am simplifying it.

Comment: My browser is telling me the links you posted have a virus attached. I will give you the benefit of the doubt but please post your code in the question itself. It makes it easier for everyone.

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/gui/url/28894bda01377deb57e44f2d911bf194d3b01a73028403f038ab4f5b1c10b6a4?nocache=1 It does appear that something is wrong with this site. Several virus scanners claim there is malware.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I find the paste code from google, maybe it has a virus.

Comment: @teapot418 Yes, I forget to delete it.

Comment: The origin code is too long, I am simplifying these code.

Comment: @ssayno You should upload it to stackoverflow nonetheless. Regardless of whether the site has a virus, it is best to upload code in code blocks.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b `server.c` code is too long, about 240 lines, but my code architecture is fixed, I am think how to modify it.

Comment: @ssayno Then you need to shorten it. There is no way that 240 lines need to be read. You should shorten it as much as possible.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b I modify `serve.c` code, now hese code also can reproduct my quesion.

Comment: This is a pain to read, but it looks like you may have gotten types confused? In the server code, you call accept. The second argument you pass is supposed to be a pointer to a sockaddr, but you pass a pointer to a sockaddr_in instead. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sockaddr-2, it looks like they are two separate struct. They may represent the same thing, which is confusing as hell, but my brain already hurts from trying to understand all of this, with none of the abbreviations and similar names helping.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b That's not a problem.   Anyplace the socket API expect a `struct sockaddr *`, you're allowed to pass the address of protocol specific sockaddr structures such as `struct sockaddr_in *` or `struct sockaddr_un *`.  Also, in APIs that accept a `struct sockaddr_storage *`, you can pass the address of a `struct sockaddr6_in`.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b "This requires that any calls to these functions must cast the pointer to the protocol-specific socket address structure to be a pointer to a generic socket address structure. ". This quote is from APUE this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your call to `accept`:

```
client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &len);
```

The value that the third parameter points to needs to be initialized with the length of the buffer that the second parameter points to.  You don't do this, so the first time `accept` is called it reads an uninitialized value.  This can lead to undefined behavior.

If you set this value properly:

```
len = sizeof client_addr;
client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &len);
```

You'll get the expected result.

Also, you're reading the values of `array_fds` without initializing them, so you need to give those initial values as well.

```
int array_fds[3] = {-1,-1,-1}, array_index = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the right results. When I write this function, I forgot to initialize the `len`,Thank you very much for your help, again.

Answer (score 1):

You *set the ip address **of the server**,* but the server *shows the ip address used **by the client*** (as you request it to be filled by the kernel, and being the loopback device the one that is requested to use, this makes the kernel not to lose time selecting any, and leaves the default `0.0.0.0` which has the meaning any local address
--- this is a clear misbehaving practice as the tcp/ip specification clearly forbids any packet to show 0.0.0.0 as origin ip in the network, except for ip assigning protocols like BOOTP or DHCP, but the packet never gets to the network in the loopback interface, so it is not, indeed, a protocol violation)  If you made a real network connection, you would also see different addresses, as the programs normally show the peer address (and not the local addres, which is normally known by everybody, except in uncommon cases)

In the second and later connections, probably the kernel has already assigned an address to the interface requested, and so, it is easy to copy that to the packet, so everything shows as expected.